# Android Writing to Internal Storage: File is Read Only

Tags: android, file

I see an issue while writing to internal storage on one specific Android device - Z988. On debug builds, I can successfully write/read files to the internal storage. But on signed builds, the files are read-only.

```
File file = new File(mApplicationContext.getFilesDir() + File.separator+ NAME); 
Log.e(TAG,"Can write to file:"+file.canWrite());
```

file.canWrite() is true on debug builds and false for signed builds. Can Proguard possibly be messing this up? I don't see anything that would affect file read/write. Then again, it does not happen on any other device and it happens for all users on this particular device model(Z988).  I don't have any external storage read write permissions in the Manifest since I'm not writing to External storage. Has anyone seen this issue before on this or any other devices?